# About TCP socket programming on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server listening on a port. When there is a new connection coming in, the server accepts the connection and gets a file descriptors from `accept()`. My question is, should this file descriptor's value be unique, or can I have two file descriptors with the same value?

Answer (score 3):

For two connections at the same time, they must have distinct file descriptors; otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish which connection's socket you care about when making a system call.

When considering two sockets that exist at different times, file descriptor numbers can and are often reused. You cannot assume their uniqueness.

Comment: Hi nanofarad, Thanks for your reply. This happens on one socket, the connections are setup at different time, actually several minutes apart, and got the same file descritpor numbers.

Comment: Yes, because file descriptors can be reused.  Once a socket descriptor is closed, the descriptor can be reused for a new connection.

Comment: Linux will always use the smallest available non-negative integer as the file descriptor. So if a socket has descriptor 5, you close it, then open a new one, the new one will get descriptor 5 unless a lower-valued descriptor is available.

Comment: But my problem is the old one hasn't been closed yet, and the new connection be assigned a same value.

Comment: @Johnny Do you have a code example that one of us can use to reproduce the issue?